# AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'AttentionBlock' on <module 'diffusers.models.attention'

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory, huggingface-transformers, kaggle

I've trained a diffusion model on Kaggle 2 months ago. I stored the Unet2Dmodel as a pickle file at a checkpoint, so that I can load it later for inference or resume training at that checkpoint.

```
def save_model(model):
  with open(f'{config.output_dir}/model.pkl','wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(model,f)

def load_model(path):
  with open(path,'rb') as f:
    return pickle.load(f)
```

This code worked well on Kaggle and Google Colab 2 months ago but when I tried to load my model.pkl file today, I got this error:
`AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'AttentionBlock' on <module 'diffusers.models.attention' from '/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/diffusers/models/attention.py'>`

Thanks,

I've tried to change the diffusers library to the version that I used 2 months ago but there is no change.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it isn't working for you to use the same version of diffusers that worked before, but, from [this](https://github.com/huggingface/diffusers/pull/3387) it appears that AttentionBlock has been replaced by just Attention. From [here](https://github.com/huggingface/diffusers/pull/2697) it sounds like you may be able to use `_convert_deprecated_attention_blocks` to update your model.